# React state not updating in app but I can console.log correct updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a form I have created using es6 class. The form is stateful and updates its state onChange. The information in the state of the form is passed up to the app component onSubmit. I can console.log every step through through the state being passed up in the methods of my form and app component and it is behaving as expected. In this code example I have the console after I setState in app and it logs out the state object with the input value added as I would expect.

The problem is when I look in the react developer tools, the state has not updated. Also, if I move the console statement into a callback function in the setState method, it does not log anything.

My questions are how to fix this and more importantly, why would I be able to log out the state with the values I am looking for when the state in the application has does not appear to have actually updated?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      appointments: [{title:'first appointment'}]
    };
    this.updateAppointments = this.updateAppointments.bind(this);
  }

  updateAppointments(newAppointment) {
    var newAppointmentList = this.state.appointments;
    newAppointmentList.push(newAppointment);
    this.setState= {
      appointments: newAppointmentList,
      //This console logs nothing
      function() {
        console.log(this.state.appointments);
      }
    }; 
    //This console logs out the state as expected with the new appointment 
    //added even thought the state in the app does not appear to have the 
    //appointment added when I look in the react dev tools  
    console.log(this.state.appointments);  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppointmentForm addAppointment = {this.updateAppointments} />        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AppointmentForm extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      appointmentTitle: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleTitleChange(event) {
    this.setState({appointmentTitle: event.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    let newAppointment = {
      title: this.state.appointmentTitle
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addAppointment(newAppointment);
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>          
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <FormGroup controlId="appointmentTitle">
              <ControlLabel>Appointment Title</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Appointment Title" value={this.state.appointmentTitle}
              onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
            </FormGroup>
          </form>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are updating the state in wrong way.

Instead of:

```
this.setState = {
```

Write it like this:

```
updateAppointments(newAppointment) {
    var newAppointmentList = this.state.appointments.slice();
    newAppointmentList.push(newAppointment);
    this.setState({
        appointments: newAppointmentList, () => {
           console.log(this.state.appointments);
        }
    }) 
}
```

**Suggestion:** Never mutate the state value directly, so first create a copy of `state` array by using `slice()`, push the new value then use `setState` to update the `state`.

Comment: Thank you! Does your suggestion have something to do with stepping through state with the redux tools? I haven't dove into redux yet but I feel like I have read about that type of situation.

Comment: that was for react component, in redux also inside you should never mutate the state values, check this statement, **"Reducers are “pure functions”. They should not have any side-effects nor mutate the state — they must return a modified copy."** check this article: https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3

Answer (score 2):

You have a code error. You're setting the `setState` property, not calling the setState function. Change this:

```
this.setState= {
  appointments: newAppointmentList,
  function() {
    console.log(this.state.appointments);
  }
};
```

to this:

```
this.setState({
  appointments: newAppointmentList,
  function() {
    console.log(this.state.appointments);
  }
});
```

Comment: "You're setting the setState property, not calling the setState function." Just like they specifically say not to do in the docs. Thank you!